# Break JSON list of values into rows in a SNOWFLAKE database table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a table as per the below screenshot which is basically a JSON and is parsed to get the output below, now I want the list of values in column City and orders to be split into rows.

Could someone please help me

[image]

Desired Output is as below

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do it. First get rid of the [" and ]" as the double quotes in city column don't enclose single array elements but all of them, then tokenize the string and return it as real array with strtok_to_array, then flatten the array elements to separate rows and lateral join the rows (cities) back to the rest of the record.

```
with data as
(select 'A' as name, 'M' as gender, '["completed"]' as orders, '["Cochi,Hyderabad"]' as city
union all
 select 'B' as name, 'M' as gender, '["completed"]' as orders, '["Cochi,Hyderabad,Delhi"]' as city
union all
 select 'C' as name, 'F' as gender, '["cancelled"]' as orders, '["Mumbai,Pune"]' as city
union all
 select 'D' as name, 'M' as gender, '["pending"]' as orders, '["cochi"]' as city
)
, data2 as 
( select d.name
 , d.gender
 , replace(replace(d.orders,'["',''),'"]','') as orders
 , strtok_to_array(replace(replace(city,'["',''),'"]',''),',')  as city
 from data d
)
 select d2.name
 , d2.gender
 , d2.orders
 , replace(c.value,'"','') as city
 from data2 d2
  , lateral flatten(input => d2.city) c;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array in the `city` field is actually an array containing a single comma-separated string like `["Cochi, Hyderabad"]`, it needs the third level of flattening with `STRTOK_TO_ARRAY` as below:

```
create or replace table t1 (json variant) as
select parse_json('{"Name": "A", "Gender": "M", "orders": ["completed"], "city": ["Cochi, Hyderabad"]}')
union all
select parse_json('{"Name": "B", "Gender": "M", "orders": ["completed"], "city": ["Cochi, Hyderabad, Delhi"]}')
union all
select parse_json('{"Name": "C", "Gender": "F", "orders": ["cancelled"], "city": ["Mumbai, Pune"]}')
union all
select parse_json('{"Name": "D", "Gender": "M", "orders": ["pending"], "city": ["Cochi"]}')
;

select
    json:Name::varchar name,
    json:Gender::varchar gender,
    orders.value::varchar orders,
    city.value::varchar city
from t1,
lateral flatten(json:orders) orders,
lateral flatten(json:city) city_raw,
lateral flatten(strtok_to_array(city_raw.value, ', ')) city
;
/*
NAME    GENDER  ORDERS  CITY
A   M   completed   Cochi
A   M   completed   Hyderabad
B   M   completed   Cochi
B   M   completed   Hyderabad
B   M   completed   Delhi
C   F   cancelled   Mumbai
C   F   cancelled   Pune
D   M   pending Cochi
*/
```

`LATERAL FLATTEN` is an idiom to flatten (expand) the values in an object (JSON) or an array to rows and combine with the original row in the parent table.

So, the query above does:

- Flatten the array in the `orders` field to expand the array elements into rows of the `ORDERS` column in the output
- Flatten the array in the `city` field to expand the array elements into rows of the `CITY_RAW` intermediate column in the output
- Split the comma-separated string extracted in the `CITY_RAW` column into city names and flatten the intermediate array of the strings into rows in the `CITY` column

This way allows you to achieve the desired output without any complex string manipulation.

---

However, I suspect the array stored in the JSON is actually like `["Cochi", "Hyderabad"]`, the array of the city names quoted by double quotations for each city name.

In this case, the query will be simple; You just need to flatten the arrays in the `orders` field and the `city` field by using `LATERAL FLATTEN` for each.

```
create or replace table t2 (json variant) as
select parse_json('{"Name": "A", "Gender": "M", "orders": ["completed"], "city": ["Cochi", "Hyderabad"]}')
union all
select parse_json('{"Name": "B", "Gender": "M", "orders": ["completed"], "city": ["Cochi", "Hyderabad", "Delhi"]}')
union all
select parse_json('{"Name": "C", "Gender": "F", "orders": ["cancelled"], "city": ["Mumbai", "Pune"]}')
union all
select parse_json('{"Name": "D", "Gender": "M", "orders": ["pending"], "city": ["Cochi"]}')
;


select
    json:Name::varchar name,
    json:Gender::varchar gender,
    orders.value::varchar orders,
    city.value::varchar city
from t2,
lateral flatten(json:orders) orders,
lateral flatten(json:city) city
;
/*
NAME    GENDER  ORDERS  CITY
A   M   completed   Cochi
A   M   completed   Hyderabad
B   M   completed   Cochi
B   M   completed   Hyderabad
B   M   completed   Delhi
C   F   cancelled   Mumbai
C   F   cancelled   Pune
D   M   pending Cochi
*/
```