# Contains function with string splitting

Tags: sql, join, nlp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, match

I am trying to use a contains() function to do matching on two columns when joining tables.
I have two problems

**Problem 1**

The data looks as such:

> col1: '["Red","Blue","Green","yes","purple","car","yellow"]'
>
> col2: 'This Is Not Yellow'

SO using `contains(LOWER("col1"), LOWER("col2"))` works for some examples, however the one above will not work properly, I need to split col2 and look for each value individually in col1 which I am having trouble doing.

**Problem 2**
I also have cases that look like this:

> col1: '["House","brick","purple","blue"]'
>
> col2: 'Very big houses'

So, again the above examples col2 would need to be split and looked for individually in col1, however **houses** would need to be trimmed by 1 character from the LEFT (to make house), but some other examples might need 2 characters taken off.

For this I was inclined to put together a dictionary to swap out for the appropriate names, or use some sort of NLP stemmers technique to remove the plurals from the word.

Any help on either of those very welcome

Thanks!

Comment: this explain how you can fltten your json https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676196/break-json-list-of-values-into-rows-in-a-snowflake-database-table

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
create table t1 (
    color varchar(32)
);
insert into t1 values ('Red');
insert into t1 values ('Green');
insert into t1 values ('yes');
insert into t1 values ('purple');
insert into t1 values ('car');
insert into t1 values ('yellow');
insert into t1 values ('House');
insert into t1 values ('brick');
insert into t1 values ('blue');
create table t2(
    words varchar(100)
);
insert into t2 values ('This Is Not Yellow');
insert into t2 values ('Very big houses');
select * from t1 join t2 on t2.words like concat('%',color, '%');
```

result is exactly what you want

| color | words |
| --- | --- |
| yellow | This Is Not Yellow |
| House | Very big houses |

btw, I was using Mysql, seems like LIKE is ignoring cases. If issues move all to the same case.

```
select * from t1 join t2 on lower(t2.words) like 
concat('%',lower(color), '%');
```

Comment: Hey, so the Col1 I was referring to is a string like so: '["Red","Blue","Green","yes","purple","car","yellow"]', it is all contained in one row. If it was all separate the contains would do the same trick.

Comment: try to put some sql scripts for table creation, and fill records. It will be easier to understand requirements